# Модальное окно для react-компонента отдельно от него

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Есть react-компонент, который находится в глубине dom-дерева, и есть модальное окно, внутри которого тоже react-компонент, которое надо расположить в корне dom-а. 
Как можно передавать данные между этими react-компонентами если они не имеют общего родителя?

Comment: Через [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: как setState связывает два react-компонента?

Comment: В React `setState` единственный способ передачи данных между компонентами. Почитайте текст по ссылке, там все описано.

Comment: @hindmost довольно-таки безапелляционно!

Comment: по поводу вопроса: такая связь между компонентами это довольно редкий случай, и на 99% я уверен что задачу можно решить по-другому. Почему бы не подключить компоненты, так или иначе, к общему стору? Или, в любой случае какой-то общий родитель есть у всех компонентов (<App /> или что там у вас). Дом дерево и дерево компонентов хоть и часто совпадают, но это не обязательно.

Comment: в общем оба ваши компонента - мод. окно и просто компонент, могут иметь одного родителя и он и будет всем управлять. любой portal компонент в помощь

Comment: ```createPortal```

Comment: react-redux? ...

Comment: createPortal подходит, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> если что, я не в теме - не претендую на правильность подхода !

тем не менее, у меня вопрос:
а так уже не модно?

```
let div = _str => <div>_str</div>
```

все пишут только на классах??

```js
void function() {
  let style = (_top = 50) => `
    position:fixed;
    top:${_top}px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    border:solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
  `
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.setAttribute('style', style(50))
  div.id = 'modalBox'
  div.setAttribute('hidden', '')
  document.body.appendChild(div)
}();

// --

let modal = (_str, _click) => (<h1>{_str}
  <input type="button" value="батон" onClick={_click} />
</h1>);

//--

void function someModule() {
  let div = document.getElementById('modalBox')
  // --
  let localFoo = () => {
    removeChilds(div)
  }
  ReactDOM.render(
    modal('текст сообщения modal 2', localFoo),
    div
  )
  div.removeAttribute('hidden')
  // --
  function removeChilds(_parent) {
    Array.from(_parent.childNodes).forEach(_el => _el.remove())
    _parent.setAttribute('hidden', '')
  }
}()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```